# Pixi.js / WebGL method for converting data model coordinates to canvas pixel coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

Apologies in advance if any of my terms are incorrect.  My familiarity with WebGL vocabulary is still quite new.

I currently have a project where I'm creating a charting library.  My issue stems from the slowness of mapping points from the chart's coordinate system into the webgl canvas pixel coordinates.  For example:

```
    _____________ 100, 100
    |           |
    |           |
    |           |
    |           |
0,0 -------------
```

where my displayed points are randomly distributed between ([0,100],[0,100]).  I then need to translate the x/y values from between 0 and 100 chart-coordinates into the 0 and say 640 pixel coordinates.  While I *CAN* perform this translation in javascript, I was wondering if there was a better mechanism for doing this via WebGL techniques (like register some form of matrix transform with some inputs that the graphics card can perform faster than plain old javascript code.)

My current javascript functions converting from the model's coordinates to pixel coordinates:

```
function transformY(y, modelYmin, modelYmax, pixelYMax) {
    var numerator = y - modelYmin;
    var denominator = modelYmax - modelYmin;
    var ratio = numerator / denominator;
    var scale = ratio * pixelYMax;
    return scale;
}

function transformX(x, modelXmin, modelXmax, pixelXMax) {
    var numerator = x - modelXmin;
    var denominator = modelXmax - modelXmin;
    var ratio = numerator / denominator;
    var scale = ratio * pixelXMax;
    return scale;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a pixi based solution? Or webgl?

Comment: Either option would suffice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PIXI has a default uniform called `dimensions` which you can use in your WebGL code. Just make sure to add the uniform in your PIXI filter like so:

```
function myFilter() {
  var uniforms = {
    dimensions: {type: '4f',value: new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0])}
  }
}
```

(See for instance how `dimensions` is used in any of the default filters, such as http://pixijs.github.io/docs/filters_pixelate_PixelateFilter.js.html )

If the uniform is defined here, PIXI will automatically populate the values so that you can access your canvas width/height with the `dimensions.xy` vector in WebGL, where you can then perform the transformations.